# Aggregation of data depending on the value of the field

Tags: mysql, database, aggregation, mysql-5.6

I need to optimize one old legacy sql query that started to fail due to lack of free disk space on database server during the query execution (it uses 20 Gigs for temporary tables and exits with an error).

Query is a bit complicated as it aggregates data depending on the value of one of the fields in queried tables into different aliases. Main idea is to query table with groups of options and make values of that aliases columns of resulting table.

Samples of schemas and query are here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64e86/2/0. In the real query there are something like 10-12 opt_types in the `IN` clause.

The problem is that it's like 2.5kk rows and 18.5kk rows in both tables respectively.

On smaller amount of data (70k and 750k) this query runs perfect and in a very short amount of time.

Any idea how improve this query to make it run on large amount of data?
Database is MySQL 5.6. Query is populated to the server by bash script using native `mysql < query_file.sql` command.

PS Quiet frankly, I'm not really into understanding how this query works (to be exact, the part with using `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(...) ORDER BY ... ASC SEPARATOR ', ')`)

Comment: What is `2.5kk`? Millions?

Comment: Also put everything also in the question. Links break. Especially SQLFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

GROUP_CONCAT simply concatenates all the field values withinin the group - except nulls, they're dropped. Pretty much like SUM does, or any other aggregator function: MAX, MIN, whatever.

In this case, it yields the sorted list of all different (from each other) values with particular type that happened within the group, separated by comma.

Now to your question... increase the disk space, just that!
Cheap & simple.

Really, there's no actual ways for significant optimization of particularly THAT query.

And I presume changing it, or database schema, would break the app on the other side. Right? 
Ok, not really "break", but require logic changes, which you want to avoid.